# Getting email body without fetching attachments using ruby mail gem

Tags: ruby, imap, gmail-imap, mail-gem

I am trying to fetch the body of gmail using IMAP and ruby mail gem. It works perfectly while I fetch RFC822 field as described in [another stack overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12849967/458299). Fiedl has described the approach very nicely to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15818886) similar question.

This approach is great except it requires fetching RFC822 which also fetches all the attachments. Is there any other field or some other approach I can take not to fetch attachments but still use ruby mail gem to get the nicely decoded body?

Comment: Does this do what you need in PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024290/how-to-extract-inline-imagesnot-attachment-from-an-email-using-imap-in-php

Comment: @crizCraig, This seems to fetch the body (not sure about php's fetch_body method though), which does not work for multipart emails.

Comment: What about this (python) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597429/python-imaplib-download-gmail-text-without-downloading-the-full-attachment

Comment: @jimt, I have already tried BODY[1], it doesn't work for all type of messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse and understand the actual structure of the returned `BODYSTRUCTURE` response, see [RFC 3501, p. 56](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-56). Also remember to apply the relevant `Content-Transfer-Encoding` (like `base64` or `quoted-printable`) and employ proper charset conversion (the `charset` parameter of the `Content-Type` header of each body part). All of that information is included in the `BODYSTRUCTURE` response; consult your library's documentation to see how to get access to that.