# php imap How to get embedded images from the body (not attachments)?

Tags: php, image, imap

i'm creating an small email client for a website, it kinda looks like a chat.

Anyway my problem is getting specifically the embedded images in the email body, i've searched for a solution but all results only work with attached files and i've already made a function for that.

What i want is to get files from the section 1 of the body: imap_fetchbody($mbox, $msgno, **"1"** ).

the result is a long text with various sections, i could try to use some regex but i believe there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Does anyone who works with IMAP knows how it should be done?

Thanks

Comment: The body is probably in html format and you need to parse the body to get image tags or other parts which you are interested in

Comment: no, the string is a list of encoded data, includes the html body but also the files themself.

Comment: check the accepted solution in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024290/how-to-extract-inline-imagesnot-attachment-from-an-email-using-imap-in-php

Comment: thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update your imap.php file with the latest version and also need to use this function.

```
 $imap->setEmbed(true);
```